# Java: Recursive definition of template types

Tags: java, oop, generics

Take a look at this class declaration:

```
public abstract class AbstractTargetBuilder<T extends AbstractTargetBuilder<T, S>, S extends Target> {
...
}
```

The type `T` is defined to be a subtype of `AbstractTargetBuilder<T,S>`. What's the use of this pattern?

This code belongs to `Spotlight` library:
https://github.com/TakuSemba/Spotlight/blob/master/spotlight/src/main/java/com/takusemba/spotlight/target/AbstractTargetBuilder.java

Comment: In the context of builders, this is most often used to allow method chaining, whilst preserving the subclass of the builder that you're using. The methods of the builder will be declared as returning `T`, which can be interpreted as a "self" type (even though you can't enforce that it really is the self type; you're just relying upon people extending the class to be good citizens).